# a question related to Apple Push Notification Service iphone developement

Tags: iphone

I have 1 basic question,
server sends me badge number  = 5 first time
server sends me badgenumber  = 3 second time when my application is not running

but i seen that second time my bade number 3 is replaced by 5

but in my application i need that second time my badge number will be seen 3 + 5 = 8

is there any way to do it????

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone Notification handler only shows the badge in the latest notification message (3, or 5).  Your server needs to track the history and do any aggregation (summation in this case) that is necessary.

You might also want to clear the badge once the application is loaded or messages are read.  The app would also need to notify the server of the update.

Comment: Hello sir.
what server will do incase of user is offline
means 
when my application is not running at that time server sends me 10 badge no  for 10 messages.Now.if user reads 5 messages out of 10 in offline,badge will be set to 5.but as user is offline  server didn't get information.when user comes online  sppose server sends me 5 more badges with bade no 15  inplace of 10

how to resolve this problem

Comment: No solution for that.  You either be satisfied with inaccurate count, or just stop using the badge feature